# Filter script by word in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need Macros script for button which can sort my sheet by word on button, for example I run the script and in my sheet i can only see the rows that have this word and a second script that returns everything back.

Answer (score 0):

Are these values in the same row. You may find useful Filters and Filters view --> see documentation [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)

This creates a menu like this at the top row (it can filter whole tables, not only one row) and you tick in the values you want to see. You can also set Filter Views that are pre-sets of these selections

[image]

Comment: I need exactly the 'script on the button', on click which it will show the rows in which there a word specified in the script